# Terminal problem

Tags: command-line, python

I have set my python to python 3.7.9. Using this example [set to Python3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/410579/change-the-python3-default-version-in-ubuntu). After this I'm having a problem in my terminal. When I write a wrong command. The terminal is set to python. Like I am working on a python program.

```
$ hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg
```

Comment: You cannot change the python version that comes with Ubuntu without breaking the system.

Comment: Can I reset my terminal

Comment: You can reset python. If you wish to run other python environments, you can do so in a container.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  e RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.